# Find and Replace with Bash

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, sed

I'm trying to replace some text with other text in a configuration file. I created a script with the `sed` command but I'm getting an error.

Original Line:

```xml
<property name="encryptData">false</property>
```

New Line:

```xml
<property name="encryptData">true</property>
```

Command:

```sh
sed -i -e 's/<property name="encryptData">false</property>/<property name="encryptData">true</property>/g' /Users/User/Desktop/mirth.cfg
```

Error:

```
sed: 1: "s/<property name="encry ...": bad flag in substitute command: '<'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2461638

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command is almost perfect. Your problem is that you need to precede the slash in `</property>` with a backslash`\` like this.

```
sed -i -e 's/<property name="encryptData">false<\/property>/<property name="encryptData">true<\/property>/g' /Users/User/Desktop/mirth.cfg
```

Observed I did it for both occurrences.

In this way sed will know that this slash is part of the stream and not part of the command 's'.

Hope this fixes your issue.

Comment: That did it! I was tearing my hair out over what to escape. I tried it out for everything except the /. Thanks!

Comment: @user491764: Don't thank Torrien!  **;-)** If this answer did help, just click the little grey **☑** under the number now turning it into beautiful green.  That's the best thank you you can give him as it means which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: I tried earlier. I don't have enough reputation yet for it to show my positive vote :(

Comment: Not positive. Choose it as the right answer. Is your question, you choose the answer.

Comment: Oh! I found it!

Answer (score 1):

As the pattern you are looking for contains `/`, change the delimited for `sed` substitution command syntax. For example you can use `_` and also use pattern grouping so that you can use back-referencing in substitution:

```
sed -r 's_(<property name="encryptData">)false(</property>)_\1true\2_' /Users/User/Desktop/mirth.cfg
```

Also it is always a good idea to take a backup while using the `-i` option:

```
sed -ri.bak 's_(<property name="encryptData">)false(</property>)_\1true\2_' /Users/User/Desktop/mirth.cfg
```

Now the original file will be kept as `/Users/User/Desktop/mirth.cfg.bak` and the modified file will be `/Users/User/Desktop/mirth.cfg`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I normally make a backup, but it's usually done manually.